# What is best way to store database records in local?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have email application. Currently I store all the emails of all email accounts in SQL Server. I have 60 tables. After every 20 minutes, all emails are stored in XML file. To storing in XML is for offline purpose.

Offline: if there is no database connection, it brings all data from XML and stores in `DataSet` (60 tables). I use this `DataSet` to perform all offline operations like read mail or check mail etc.

This mechanism takes so much memory if there are thousands of emails in XML file. I think it takes so much memory because of `DataSet`. I don't dispose `DataSet` because all the data are stored in it and it use for operation in offline.

Can anybody suggest me mechanism for above situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Compact Edition to store mails locally. You'll be able to use the same queries to access data.

This is a client based SQL Server which keeps tables in a file. You don't install a SQL server to the client, you will only reference to the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll library and will use SqlServerCe specific connection object to access the data.

Microsoft download page is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709